# CSS Scaling issue when screen is set to maximize. Top of Form Element scaling improper: Dropped a CodePen

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I'm having issues with my scaling. I am new to coding and and don't want to have my question or help needed to be something vague do to a vague question of me not knowing how to ask the question so I put a code pin.

In my  the Name label will be pulled to the top of my page before my elements when scaling for a full desktop screen.

when i put the page by half it looks fine but something is wrong with how i scaled my css width or something, anyone have a solution and advice to avoid this in the Future?

https://codepen.io/Aspiring/pen/gOWOgvz

```
    
    
    
    
        
        
        Checking Practice
        
    
    
    
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        nav {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            background: cadetblue;
        }
    
        nav li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
        }
    
        nav li a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 100px;
        }
    
        input {
            position: relative;
            left: 30px;
        }
    
        #Pass {
            position: relative;
            left: 7px;
        }
    
        .sub-btn {
            position: relative;
            left: 135px;
            top: 10px
        }
    
        aside {
            float: right;
            color: blue;
            text-align: right;
            border: 2px solid blue;
            padding-right: px;
            width: 25%;
            margin-top: 5%;
        }
    
        article {
            width: 35%;
            float: right;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    
        #contact form {
            display: block;
            position: static;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    
<body>
    <header id="introducton">
        <h1>introduction</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui accusantium delectus quo laborum quis iure
            dignissimos fugit quidem, rem molestiae! Provident, quidem tempora?</p>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <h2>nav</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="asidebar">
        <aside>
            <h3>aside</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non mollitia sequi odit animi enim praesentium.
            </p>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <section>
        <article>
            <h4>ARTICAL 1</h4>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis repellat nemo id vero laudantium
                ad
                recusandae, hic unde eius repudiandae quo quasi distinctio ex? Rem incidunt facere ducimus aspernatur
                expedita!
            </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h5>ARTICAL 2</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor quae ipsum maiores? Excepturi ipsa
                voluptate
                eum modi? Explicabo saepe assumenda error in iusto minus nihil natus architecto, voluptatibus quia earum
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non aspernatur illo quia! Dolores fuga illum
                officiis veritatis quaerat quo harum similique nobis voluptatibus recusandae commodi, vero at eveniet
                laborum ut iure, dicta dignissimos?</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <div id="contact">
        <form action="/action_page.php" method="POST">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="name" id="name">
            <br>
            <label for="eMail">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="eMail">
            <br>
            <label for="Pass">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="Pass">
            <br>
            <label for="submit"></label>
            <input class="sub-btn" type="submit" id="email">

        </form>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="underline"> Contact</th>
            <th class="underline"> @gmail</th>
            <th class="underline"> Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Will Mosser</td>
            <td>will.mosser.32</td>
            <td>434-332-2222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Page Mosser</td>
            <td>ppispage</td>
            <td>434-332-4343</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <footer>
        <h6>footer</h6>
        <p>2021&copy;Copyright</p>
    </footer>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    nav {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background: cadetblue;
    }

    nav li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
    }

    nav li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px 100px;
    }

    input {
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
    }

    #Pass {
        position: relative;
        left: 7px;
    }

    .sub-btn {
        position: relative;
        left: 135px;
        top: 10px
    }

    aside {
        float: right;
        color: blue;
        text-align: right;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        padding-right: px;
        width: 25%;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }

    article {
        width: 35%;
        float: right;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    #contact form {
        display: block;
        position: static;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #contact {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

I insert

```
#contact {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

Comment: I have not got to understanding flex yet, Thank you for this help so much!!!!!

Comment: I can explain about flex. Now Flex is very important for you.

Comment: just my opinion.

Comment: How can we meet?

Answer (score 0):

```
#contact {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation why this _can also work_.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.